# UIPageViewController : partial display when swiping right

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have used the tutorial below to learn about the UIPageViewController:  [here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)

Every goes well up to the point i am swipping left. Swipe right pass to the next content view; swiping right does it too except the view is hidden to 1/3 by the right. The phenomena doesn't happen when swiping left...

Do you have any ideas for me to get out of this weird side-effect? There is perhaps a checkbox to tick that i haven't ; at this point of time i welcome any thoughts !

Brm
Stéphane

Comment: it is hard to say why with ought seeing the code you used, but why don't you download the sample project offered in that tutorial and compare it to what you built. that way you'll see where the issue might be.

Comment: i think you should pay attention to viewControllerBeforeViewController method of the delegate. may be you return viewController with no correct frame.

Comment: Can you share image 1 when you swipe left and 1 when you swipe right.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your responses and suggestions! I've found the problem. It was nevertheless interesting to see that this partial hiding of the view happens in swipe right only in scroll transition style but not page curl mode. No idea why. However, i have realised two things : 1st the root controller view has a background, similar to the page content views; 2nd was : why did i put a background in the page content view? As soon as i have removed it and change the background of the page content view to Clear colour (meaning none); the swipe hiding bug disappear.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I just realized it was a problem with the `UIImageView`.

In `-(void)viewDidLoad of PageContentViewController.m`, add this line of code:

```
self.backgroundImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Setting clipsToBounds (either programmatically or simply in the interface builder) solved my issue.